# android app runs on 2.3 device, crashes on 4.1 (reposting)

Tags: android

I have an Android App that is running perfectly on a version 2.3 device and one particular 4.1 emulator. It crashes on other 4.1 emulators as well as 4.1 Google Nexus device.

Any ideas?

Does this have anything to do with the size, resolution etc?

Here's the logcat output when I run it on a 4.1 emulator. Actually the code is huge, so can't really put that up here. Any hints would be great. Then I could put up the required code snippet.

```
10-01 11:42:30.404: E/Trace(623): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2) 
10-01 11:42:30.754: D/dalvikvm(623): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 126K, 3% free 8126K/8327K, paused 42ms, total 44ms
10-01 11:42:30.794: D/AndroidRuntime(623): Shutting down VM 
10-01 11:42:30.794: W/dalvikvm(623): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300) 
10-01 11:42:30.804: E/AndroidRuntime(623): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
10-01 11:42:30.804: E/AndroidRuntime(623): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.example.android_compliance/com.example.android_compliance.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException 
10-01 11:42:30.804: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
10-01 11:42:30.804: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
10-01 11:42:30.804: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
10-01 11:42:30.804: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
10-01 11:42:30.804: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
10-01 11:42:30.804: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
10-01 11:42:30.804: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
10-01 11:42:30.804: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
10-01 11:42:30.804: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
10-01 11:42:30.804: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
10-01 11:42:30.804: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
10-01 11:42:30.804: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
10-01 11:42:30.804: E/AndroidRuntime(623): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException     
10-01 11:42:30.804: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at com.example.android_compliance.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:261)
10-01 11:42:30.804: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008) 
10-01 11:42:30.804: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
10-01 11:42:30.804: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
10-01 11:42:30.804: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  ... 11 more 
10-01 11:43:33.693: I/Process(623): Sending signal. PID: 623 SIG: 9
```

Comment: What's at com.example.android_compliance.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:261)?

Comment: Also, can we see your manifest?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried applying the range of the app's SDK version in the manifest file?

Like for example the line that looks like this:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:maxSdkVersion="15"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to make some changes in your AndroidManifest file. They have changed some permissions and the like.

Comment: umm...i have used a lot of permissions..any help with which specific ones? i cd search online but any directions would make it easier...thanks!!

Comment: i have figured out the problem. one of the functions i have used returns a null value for 4.1. will put up details in some time. not allowed to answer my own question for the next few hours!!

Comment: so you found out why your function returns null in api16?

Comment: android.provider.Settings.System.TEXT_SHOW_PASSWORD should return either 1 or 0. if i run the app on 4.1 with the password visible setting enabled..it crashes. if the setting is disabled it runs perfectly. after it has run once, it runs smoothly even after changing the setting...returning the required 0 or 1.

Comment: i am adding an extra case to catch nulls..but this shdnt be happening shd it? and not just the emulator..i think its happening on ICS devices too. tested once on a friend's nexus. hvnt access to it now to confirm my theory..

Answer (score 0):

so herez the method that returns null on 4.1

```
public String visiblepassword() {
        String inputm = android.provider.Settings.System.getString(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.TEXT_SHOW_PASSWORD);
        return inputm;

        }
```

very very strangely it returns null in only one scenario...when i install the app on the device for the first time with the visible password setting enabled. so if i install first with setting disabled, it works fine. once installed, it works fine even if i change the setting and rerun the app. after initial install it returns the appropriate 1 or 0.

any ideas?

Comment: Not really, i created some special cases to deal with such scenarios.

Comment: will take me a while to get the exact code but i will get back to you soon.

Comment: I checked my code. All that I have done is add an extra case checking if the returned value is null. And if so I have explicitly made it 1. code: if(inputm==null){inputm="1";}. you can handle the null as you want, but this is not a proper soln at all!